# CSS transition working only one way "top" with position absolute on React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

The `chart-item-wrapper` class, whose `top` is adjusted using JS, smoothly moves upwards with the expected `transition` when decreased. However, when increased, it abruptly teleports downwards without a smooth animation. Why is the animation one-sided?

When I create an object from a `chart-item-wrapper` class that React didn't determine the `top` for, an object that doesn't move automatically, and manually change its `top` value via Chrome Developer Tools, the animation works smoothly bidirectionally.

Here is the screen recording of the result (I increased 1s to 7s, just to see the bug easily):
[image]

Here is the relevant part of the code that might be needed:

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="chart-title">{chartTitle}</div>
      <Area data={barData}>
        {barData.map( (item, index) => renderBarItem(item, index) )}
      </Area>
    </>
  )
```

---

```
const renderBarItem = (item, index) => {
    let rate = item.value / sortedBarData[0].value
    const percentageDivWidth = rate * 95
    
    return item.value !== 0 ?
      <ChartItem
        key={item.id}
        backgroundColor={item.color}
        width={percentageDivWidth+"%"}
        title={item.title}
        value={item.value}
        top={(index===0?20:(index*40)+20)+'px'}  // Every bar has 40px height
      />
      :
      false

  }
```

---

```
const ChartItem = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="chart-item-wrapper" style={{top: props.top, width: props.width}}>
            <div className="chart-item-bar" style={{backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor}}>
                {props.title}
            </div>
            <div className="chart-item-text">
                {props.value}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

```
.chart-item-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    top: 1px;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.chart-item-bar {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 5px;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: monospace;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 30px;
}

.chart-item-text {
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

EDIT: I made a cross-browser test with Chrome and Firefox, and the result is the same.

EDIT2: I would like to share the repository directly, so you can easily reproduce the bug: https://github.com/tatoline/react_bar_chart_race/tree/demo-algorithm-improvement